# Image missing on different computer

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I produce presentations with beamer using a custom style. A part of that style is my affiliation logo. However I found I have a problem, where the logo is missing when I send the pdf to a different computer that does not have my theme.

While I found a workaround - if I print the pdf again as a pdf in a pdf viewer the image then appears. I am wondering though if there is a TeX command to do that already when the pdf is produced. Also I use pdflatex (either OS X with mactex2016 or linux with TexLive-2015).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. You do `pdflatex beamer.tex` and you get a `beamer.pdf` file. If you open this file locally, it shows the image. If you send the **pdf** file to another computer, the image disappears? Maybe your question gets clearer if you post the code of your custom style. Before posting any code, please have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Maybe the logo file is somehow broken? Open the image with e.g. `preview`, save it, compile your document again and test if you can now view it on a different machine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: well this is embarrassing - while producing a MWE I cannot reproduce my problems. the pdf I noticed the issues on, does not show the logo on the Windows machine I am using to test this (together with the free adobe viewer), however with the MWE it shows. I think my test machine might have issues. I will do a fresh install and check.

Comment: ok reinstalled wins and I cannot reproduce the problem. even my problematic file has been fixed. so it was some bug with the installation of the pdf reader or whatever. Feel free to delete/close/whatever this, and I'm sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a reinstallation solved the problem (see last comment of OP).